# Working of Truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-compile

The following is my code in solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract DappToken {
  //Constructor
  // set no of Tokens
  // Read the total number of Tokens
  uint256 public totalSupply;

  function DappToken () public {
    totalSupply = 10000000;
  }
}
```

Now i am going to interact with Truffle 
1) I have done Truffle migrate

2) In  Truffle console i used 
DappToken.deployed().then(function(i) {token = i ;})

3)deployed() returns a promise and then takes a call back (correct me if I am wrong )

4) Next i used

```
 token.totalSupply 
{ [Function]
  call: [Function],
  sendTransaction: [Function],
  request: [Function: bound ],
  estimateGas: [Function] }
```

// It is showing the following output

> totalSupply is the name of the variable which i have given but it is
>   showing Function in square brackets can any one explain how truffle is
>   compiling inside and why it is showing me as Function 
>   I tried  **token.DappToken.totalSupply** it is showing me error I thought it 
>   will go inside the  contract and call the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solidity do not expose variables directly, but it creates a public getter function.

Your example will behave like this.

```
contract DappToken {
  uint256 public _totalSupply;

  function DappToken () public {
    _totalSupply = 10000000;
  }
  function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
    return _totalSupply;
  }
}
```

To get the total supply you have to make a call like regular function.

```
token.totalSupply().then((result) => { console.log(result); } )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [documentation](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/interacting-with-your-contracts#making-a-call). I think you need to call `token.totalSupply` inside `then()` similar to the example below:

```
var account_one = "0x1234..."; // an address

var meta;
MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) {
  meta = instance;
  return meta.getBalance.call(account_one, {from: account_one});
}).then(function(balance) {
  // If this callback is called, the call was successfully executed.
  // Note that this returns immediately without any waiting.
  // Let's print the return value.
  console.log(balance.toNumber());
}).catch(function(e) {
  // There was an error! Handle it.
})
```